# Cygnus X-1, HDE 226868 radial velocity and mass function

Tags: black-holes, data

Where could I find the data of the Radial Velocity for the visible companion (an O class star) for the binary system of Cygnus X-1?
Also for this system, we have the mass function
$$ f(M)=\dfrac{PK_C^3}{2\pi G}=\dfrac{M(BH)\sin^3 i}{(1+q)^2}$$
and where $q=M_C/M(BH)$. As $q$ depends on $M(BH)$, what kind of analysis could I do for fitting or extracting $M(BH)$ if I know $P$ and $K_C$ from my previous data fit and the radial velocity data of the companion (provided I find a database where those data are), where $P$ is the orbital period of the system?

Comment: If you just have a one-parameter fit and a bunch of data points, why not just monte-carlo the thing?

Comment: I don't know how to do a MonteCarlo...

Comment: Define an error function (say, sum of squares).  Randomly pick values for the BH mass.  Guess and check.  Pick the value that minimizes the error function.

Comment: You can get more sophisticated than that to save compute time, but that's the idea.